# How to retrieve specific user data during a session

Tags: user-data

I have a profile system set up on my site where users can sign up, fill in their username, password, and a short "about me" description. When viewing their profile, I can't seem to get the "about me" stuff to show up correctly. It keeps displaying ALL of the aboutme information from every user on the table instead of the current user's profile.

Here's what I have

```
$query = mysql_query("select aboutme from plus_signup");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
echo $row['aboutme']. " ";

}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you request on ALL your table, without conditions.

Maybe you missed something like

```
$query = mysql_query("select aboutme from plus_signup where id=".$user_id);
...
```

Comment: That didn't seem to work either. When I use that, it simply doesn't display. Even when I changed the variables to the ones that are used in the site.